# Adding an EventListener with an function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, event-handling, addeventlistener

I want to add an event listener to a button. The function which should be called on click gets passed as an argument. So it looks like this

```
public addButton(argFunction: Function) {
        const button: HTMLElement = document.createElement("button")

        button.addEventListener("click", argFunction);
    }

myclass.addButton(function(){
        console.log("test");
});
```

Trying to add the event listener this way results in TypeScript saying "The argument from type "Function" cannot get assigned to the parameter with Type "(this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any" (Roughly translated by me).

When i declare a function inside the addButton it works:

```
public addButton(argFunction: Function) {
        const button: HTMLElement = document.createElement("button")

        var f = function () {
            console.log("f")
        };

        button.addEventListener("click", argFunction);
    }
```

Why does this work and how can i pass a function as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use other type for your listener function:

```js
type Listener = (ev: MouseEvent) => void

// alternative way
interface Listener2 {
  (ev: MouseEvent): void
}


class Foo {
  public addButton(argFunction: Listener) {
    const button: HTMLElement = document.createElement("button")

    button.addEventListener("click", argFunction);
  }
}
const foo = new Foo()

foo.addButton(function () {
  console.log("test");
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMgSwM4igOygJxgXhgCigDcAuGAWQHsBXJKAUSPRAEpcA%20GIyhAE2GABjADYBDJEhgAxSpRgBvYDBgRqAI2EJBMUb14AhaiBCU0%20UZgDmU6mkEgEpsohTosbRcuWDTKGGqMTNDIACQAVcjh6YSgAW2ZcGF5KQWp4tBAAOkFMKFFUaLjmfAAiAONTEpYBL39A00zdXkZmF1QMTFKRLQBrEoAaHSsbOwdTFgBuJRgAX2A5nzQ-ADNZRIwAd2lZfGrgVcpGvUMKs2Xbe0c0Ag9pxaRKGMzhSktS1BQqqZnJoA)

Try to avoid capitalized constructor types like `Function`, `String`, `Number`, `Object`

In 99% cases it is better to use `type Fn = (...args:any[])=>any` instead of `Function`

> I realized that types like String show errors instead of string. Is there a difference between them?

Yes, the is a difference. `String`, `Number` are constructor types, pretty much like `Array`. But when you create a simple string like `foo`, you don't use `String` constructor, like `String('foo')`. You just use literal `foo`.

Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean)

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!I realized that types like ```String``` show errors instead of ```string```. Is there a difference between them?